# ImportError when running Python tests: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import

I'm working on a Python project where I've set up a package with some modules. The simplified project structure looks like this:

```
project-root/
├── package-prototype/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── test/
│   │   └── test_main.py
```

I'm trying to write tests for the functions in `main.py`, but I'm encountering an `ImportError` when running the tests. Specifically, I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` for the package I'm trying to import.

Here's the relevant code in `test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from package_prototype.src import main

class TestAddFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    # Test cases here...
```

Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how I can correctly import my package for testing?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information**:

I'm using Python 3.11.4.
I'm working on a Windows11 machine.

I've tried several methods to set the `PYTHONPATH` both in the command prompt, but I'm still facing this issue.

```
...\Desktop\package-prototype> set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%CD%
%CD% : The term '%CD%' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:29
+ set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%CD%
+                             ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (%CD%:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```